# Is it possible to put a custom GUI on top of an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, user-interface

A friend of mine has a very complex Excel spreadsheet with many formulas and lots of data that he uses for work. He wants to put a custom GUI on top of it and then wants to sell it to other people in his profession. Basically he wants to make some freestanding software out of his spreadsheet? Is there any way to put a custom GUI on top of an Excel spread sheet? The spreadsheet would just reside in the backend and be a kind of database and do the calculations necessary. I know this is definitely not an elegant solution but I told him I'd look into it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Clear Office](http://www.clearoffice.com).

You can host workbooks in your GUI, host GUI in your workbook. All .NET, no interop.

Comment: that link does not work. Any recent developments on excel based UX?

Answer (score 0):

[Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28office.11%29.aspx) fits the bill.  Code your GUI with WinForms/WPF and .NET; invoke excel in the background to be your calculation engine.  Pretty ugly (and probably slow) solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the book [Professional Excel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321262506) by Bovey.  It talks about how to do some radical Excel customizations along the lines of what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex the application/input is, he may be able to use **[userforms](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829070)**, which are built in to Excel.  Alternately, he can **set up a sheet as in input form**, and use other sheets for data/calculations, and super-hide them.  We made a spreadsheet for a company at work, and used both solutions.  Userforms can be frustratingly inflexible, but they work.

You can also add in some VBA to show the Userform when the workbook is opened, although if macros are disabled (which they are by default) then it won't work.